# Why npm install give different result folder than yarn install

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

So I am trying to install specific version of **lib-jitsi-meet** package with the following commands:

```
npm install "https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet.git#b0356800"

yarn add "https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet.git#b0356800"
```

But inside node_modules/lib-jitsi-meet I got different results:

npm install:

[image]

yarn add:

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to force **npm** to get same results as **yarn** gives?